# Remote work advice?

Tags: editing, business-writing, career

I apologize if this is a tedious question but …

My wife and I may be moving overseas soon and I have been considering looking for work that I can do remotely, possibly writing.  My background is that I have an MA in music and am a professional jazz musician.  I also worked in high-tech for many years and studied engineering.  I’m well read and write English well.  I’ve also sidelined privately as a tutor for years (academics, SAT, GRE, etc.) and have done some editing and proofreading.

So, I was wondering if there is some kind of writing that I can do.  When I scan many of the freelance writing sites, I see many writing, editing, etc. jobs but often offering scandalously low compensation.  Of course, there are a lot of people around the world willing to do it cheaply.

I was wondering about grant writing.  I see requests for grant writing come up from time to time and realize that being more specialized work, it might not attract as many low bidders.  I see advertisements for seminars for grant writers but I wonder if it’s a waste of money.  Are there any grant writers here?  Is this a reasonable plan?  Can I become a successful grant writer taking a class and working remotely, from overseas?

I’m not looking to get rich.  I just want something that I can do part-time and make a respectable wage to supplement my income.  What can I do remotely from overseas?  I don't mind hard work and won't mind investing some time and money building this, I just don't want to go down the wrong path and end up in a scam or dead-end.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanx,
Kevin

Comment: Kevin, welcome to Stack Exchange. I recommend that you review the Help Center to get a better idea of what type of Q&A this platform is designed to support. [How do I ask a good question?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good starting place. It appears to me that you are looking for an open-ended conversation, which is more appropriate for a message board or discussion forum. If you can [edit] your question so that it is more focused on a specific problem, rather than a complicated set of loosely-related concerns, it might improve your chances of a useful answer.

Comment: @Air is quite correct. I'm putting this on-hold for the moment, but if you can edit this to a focused question, I'll be happy to reopen. Either way, best of luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but grant writing is a very, very specialised area, in my experience. It does depend on what type of grants, of course, but I would be very wary of anyone charging money to teach grant writing -- institutions and groups that want grants provide experts to help those applying.